# Issue inserting bulk data through DataTable with MS Sql Stored Procedure in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, insert, bulk

I have to situation where i'm inserting bulk data into some sql table. I'm sending all rows through DataTable in c#. Every row performs some calculation in stored procedure based on data.

The problem is everything works fine when i put **Thread.Sleep(2000)** before opening the database connection, but when i remove that, rows insert without any issue but calculation goes bad.

```
public async Task<SqlResponseGet> SyncOrderBook(List<UserOrderBook> Data, int SubsUserID)
    {

        SqlResponseGet response = new SqlResponseGet();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("USP_User_SyncPositions_Bulk", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            #region Build DataTable
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("OrderBookTable");
            dt.Columns.Add("_ID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("SubsUserID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Exchange", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("InstrumentType", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("OptionType", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("StrikePrice", typeof(decimal));
            dt.Columns.Add("Expiry", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("OrderID", typeof(long));
            dt.Columns.Add("TradeID", typeof(long));
            dt.Columns.Add("ExchangeOrderID", typeof(long));
            dt.Columns.Add("Symbol", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("ShortSymbol", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("SignalType", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("OrderType", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("ProductType", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(decimal));
            dt.Columns.Add("OrderQty", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("TradedQty", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("SquareOff", typeof(bool));
            dt.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Message", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Strategy", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("PaperTrading", typeof(bool));
            dt.Columns.Add("TimeStamp", typeof(DateTime));

            int i = 1;
            foreach (UserOrderBook order in Data)
            {
                #region Date Formatting
                string Expiry = null;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(order.Expiry))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Expiry = DateTime.Parse(order.Expiry).ToSqlDateFormat();
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
                #endregion

                #region Strike Formatting
                decimal Strike = 0;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(order.StrikePrice.Trim()))
                {
                    Strike = decimal.Parse(order.StrikePrice);
                }
                #endregion

                dt.Rows.Add(i++, order.ID, order.SubsUserID, order.Exchange, order.Instrument, order.OptionType, Strike,
                    Expiry, order.OrderID, order.TradeID, order.ExchangeOrderID, order.Symbol, order.ShortSymbol, order.SignalType,
                    order.OrderType, order.ProductType, order.Price, order.OrderQty, order.TradedQty, order.SquareOff, order.Status,
                    order.Message, order.Strategy, order.PaperTrading, order.TimeStamp.HasValue ? order.TimeStamp : DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(i*10));
            }
            #endregion
            //SqlParameter parameter = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderBookTable", dt);
            SqlParameter parameter=new SqlParameter();
            parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
            parameter.TypeName = "dbo.OrderBookTable";
            parameter.ParameterName = "@OrderBookTable";
            parameter.Value = dt;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);

            try
            {
                await con.OpenAsync();
                //Thread.Sleep(2000);
                if (await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync() > 0)
                {
                    response = new SqlResponseGet
                    {
                        Code = SqlCode.Created,
                        Message = "Record created.",
                        data = Data
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    response = new SqlResponseGet
                    {
                        Code = SqlCode.NotCreated,
                        Message = "Record not created.",
                    };
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                response = new SqlResponseGet
                {
                    Code = SqlCode.SqlException,
                    Message = "Record not created. Internal Error."
                };
            }                
        }

        return response;
    }
```

When i execute same procedure with same data in Sql Server Management Studio, everything works fine.

Below is the stored procedure

```
alter Proc [dbo].USP_User_SyncPositions_Bulk       
 @OrderBookTable [OrderBookTable] READONLY      
As      
 DECLARE @RowCount int = (select count(ID) from @OrderBookTable)    
 DECLARE @K int = 1  

 --LOOP THROUGH RECORDS  
 WHILE @K <= @RowCount  
 BEGIN  
  DECLARE @Strategy VARCHAR(50), @InstrumentType VARCHAR(10),@OrderType VARCHAR(20)    
  DECLARE @Exchange VARCHAR(50), @ProductType VARCHAR(20), @OptionType VARCHAR(10)    
  DECLARE @SubsUserID int, @Status VARCHAR(100), @TradedQty INT, @OrderQty int    
  DECLARE @ExchangeOrderID BIGINT, @OrderID BIGINT, @TradeID BIGINT, @ID int  
  DECLARE @SignalType varchar(20), @Symbol VARCHAR(100), @Price money, @StrikePrice money  
  DECLARE @ShortSymbol varchar(50), @Expiry VARCHAR(50), @Message VARCHAR(500), @Timestamp DATETIME  
  DECLARE @SquareOff bit, @PaperTrading bit  

  SELECT  @SubsUserID = SubsUserID, @Strategy = Strategy,     
    @InstrumentType = InstrumentType, @OrderType=OrderType, @ProductType=ProductType,    
    @OptionType=OptionType, @Exchange=Exchange, @Status = [Status], @TradedQty=TradedQty,    
    @OrderQty=OrderQty, @ID = ID, @ExchangeOrderID=ExchangeOrderID, @OrderID=OrderID,    
    @TradeID=TradeID, @Symbol = Symbol, @Price = Price, @StrikePrice = StrikePrice,  
    @ShortSymbol = ShortSymbol, @Expiry = Expiry, @Timestamp = [TimeStamp], @Message = [Message],  
    @SquareOff = SquareOff, @PaperTrading = PaperTrading, @SignalType = SignalType  
  
  FROM @OrderBookTable WHERE _id = @K  

  --Process Record  
  DECLARE @StrategyID Int,@InstrumentTypeID Int,@OrderTypeID Int,@ExchangeID Int  
  DECLARE @ProductTypeID Int,@OptionTypeID Int      
  Set @StrategyID=((Select st.Id From Subsuserstrategy st Join Adminstrategy ast On ast.Id = st.Strategyid Join Strategy s On s.Id = ast.Strategyid Where  s.Strategyname = @Strategy And st.Subsuserid = @SubsUserID))      
  Set @InstrumentTypeID=((Select Id From Subsuserinstrumenttype Where Name = @InstrumentType))          
  Set @OrderTypeID = (Select Id From Subsuserordertype Where Name = @OrderType)      
     Set @ExchangeID = (Select Id From Subsuserexchange Where Name = @Exchange)      
  Set @ProductTypeID = (Select Id From   Subsuserproducttype Where  Name = @ProductType)      
  Set @OptionTypeID = (Select Id From   Subsuseroptiontype Where  Name = @OptionType)      
  
  ---------------------------------CALCULATE MTM---------------------------------------              
  If @SignalType = 'SELL' Or @SignalType = 'COVER'      
  Begin       
   Create Table #temp      
   (      
    _id        Int Identity(1, 1),      
    Signaltype VARCHAR(15),      
    Symbol     VARCHAR(50),      
    Price      Money,      
    Orderqty   Money,      
    Tradedqty  Money      
   )      
  
   Insert Into #temp      
   Select Signaltype,      
     Symbol,      
     Price,      
     Orderqty,      
     Tradedqty      
   From   Subsuserorderbook      
   Where  Subsuserid = @SubsUserID      
     And Convert(Date, Datecreated) = Convert(Date, Getdate())      
     And Symbol = @Symbol      
     And Datecreated < Getdate()      
   Order  By Symbol,      
     Datecreated      
  
   --select * from #temp              

   DECLARE @count Int =(Select Count(_id)      
   From   #temp)      
   DECLARE @i Int=@count      
   DECLARE @_SignalType VARCHAR(15),      
     @_Symbol     VARCHAR(50),      
     @_Price      Money,      
     @_OrderQty   Money,      
     @_TradedQty  Money      
   DECLARE @TotalCost Money=0      
   DECLARE @TotalQty Money=0      
  
   While @i >= 1      
   Begin      
    Select @_SignalType = Signaltype,      
      @_Symbol = Symbol,      
      @_Price = Price,      
      @_OrderQty = Orderqty,      
      @_TradedQty = Tradedqty      
    From   #temp      
    Where  _id = @i      
      And Symbol = @Symbol      
  
    --Print @SignalType +' '+ @Symbol               
                  
    If @_SignalType = 'SELL' And @i = @count      
     Begin      
      --do nothing              
      Set @i = @i - 1      
  
      Continue;      
     End      
    Else    --BUY  
     Begin      
      If @_SignalType = 'BUY'      
      Begin      
       --Print convert(VARCHAR(10),@i) + ' ' + @SignalType +' '+ @Symbol              
       --select * from #temp where _ID=@i                 
       If @TotalQty < @TradedQty      
        Begin      
         Set @TotalCost += @_TradedQty * @_Price      
         Set @TotalQty += @_TradedQty      
        --select * from #temp where _ID=@i                 
        End      
       Else      
        Begin      
         Break;      
        End      
      End      
     End      
  
    If @_SignalType = 'COVER'      
     And @i = @count      
     Begin      
      --do nothing              
      Set @i = @i - 1      
  
      Continue;      
     End      
    Else      
     Begin      
      If @_SignalType = 'SHORT'      
      Begin      
       --Print convert(VARCHAR(10),@i) + ' ' + @SignalType +' '+ @Symbol              
       --select * from ##pnl where _ID=@i                 
       If @TotalQty < Abs(@TradedQty)      
        Begin      
         Set @TotalCost += @_TradedQty * @_Price      
         Set @TotalQty += @_TradedQty      
        --select * from #pnl where _ID=@i                 
        End      
       Else      
        Begin      
         Break;      
        End      
      End      
     End      
  
    Set @i = @i - 1      
   End      
  
   --DECLARE @AvgPrice Money      
  
   --Set @AvgPrice = @TotalCost / @TotalQty      
  
   --select @TotalQty TotalQty, @AvgPrice AvgPrice              
   DECLARE @PnL Money      
   DECLARE @TotalBuyPrice Money      
   DECLARE @TotalSellPrice Money      
  
   Set @TotalBuyPrice = Abs(@TotalCost)      
   Set @TotalSellPrice = Abs(@Price * @TradedQty)      
  
   If @SignalType = 'SELL'      
   Begin      
    Set @PnL = @TotalSellPrice - @TotalBuyPrice      
   End      
   Else      
   Begin      
    Set @PnL = @TotalBuyPrice - @TotalSellPrice      
   End      
  
   --select @Price Price, @TotalCost TotalCost,@TotalQty TotalQty,@AvgPrice AvgPrice,@TotalBuyPrice TotalBuyPrice,@TotalSellPrice TotalSellPrice,@PnL PnL              
   Drop Table #temp          
  End      
  Else  
  BEGIN  
   SET @Pnl = NULL  
  END  
  ---------------------------------CALCULATE MTM---------------------------------------              
  --Tranches Fix                      
  --If @OrderType = 'MARKET' And (@Status = 'filled' Or @Status = 'complete')      
  --  Begin      
  --      Set @TradedQty = @OrderQty      
  --  End      
  
  --GetBroker          
  DECLARE @AdminBrokerID Int      
  
  Set @AdminBrokerID = (Select Adminbrokerid      
        From   Subsuser      
        Where  Id = @SubsUserID)      
  
  If @ID = 0      
  Begin      
  --print 'check inserting:' + convert(varchar(100),@ExchangeOrderID)+'-'+convert(varchar(100),@OrderID)+'-'+convert(varchar(100),@TradeID)+'-'+convert(varchar(100),@SubsUserID)
   If Not Exists (Select Id      
       From   Subsuserorderbook      
       Where  Exchangeorderid = @ExchangeOrderID      
        And Orderid = @OrderID      
        And Tradeid = @TradeID      
        And Subsuserid = @SubsUserID)      
   Begin      
   print 'inserting'
    Insert Into [dbo].[Subsuserorderbook]      
       ([Subsuserid],      
        [Exchangeid],      
        [Adminbrokerid],      
        [Instrumenttypeid],      
        [Orderid],      
        [Tradeid],      
        [Exchangeorderid],      
        [Symbol],      
        [Shortsymbol],      
        [Signaltype],      
        [Expiry],      
        [Strike],      
        [Optiontypeid],      
        [Ordertypeid],      
        [Producttypeid],      
        [Price],      
        [Orderqty],      
        [Tradedqty],      
        [Status],      
        [Message],      
        [Strategyid],      
        [Datecreated],      
        [Dateupdated],      
        [Squareoff],      
        [Papertrading],      
        [Realizedpnl])      
    Values(@SubsUserID,      
        @ExchangeID,      
        @AdminBrokerID,      
        @InstrumentTypeID,      
        @OrderID,      
        @TradeID,      
        @ExchangeOrderID,      
        @Symbol,      
        @ShortSymbol,      
        @SignalType,      
        @Expiry,      
        @StrikePrice,      
        @OptionTypeID,      
        @OrderTypeID,      
        @ProductTypeID,      
        @Price,      
        @OrderQty,      
        @TradedQty,      
        @Status,      
        @Message,      
        @StrategyID,      
        @TimeStamp,      
        @TimeStamp,      
        @SquareOff,      
        @PaperTrading,      
        @PnL)       
   End         
  End      
  Else      
   Begin      
   print 'updating'
    Update [dbo].[Subsuserorderbook]      
    Set    [Exchangeid] = @ExchangeID,      
      [Instrumenttypeid] = @InstrumentTypeID,      
      [Orderid] = @OrderID,      
      [Tradeid] = @TradeID,      
      [Exchangeorderid] = @ExchangeOrderID,      
      [Symbol] = @Symbol,      
      [Signaltype] = @SignalType,      
      [Ordertypeid] = @OrderTypeID,      
      [Producttypeid] = @ProductTypeID,      
      [Price] = @Price,      
      [Orderqty] = @OrderQty,      
      [Tradedqty] = @TradedQty,      
      [Status] = @Status,      
      [Message] = @Message,      
      [Strategyid] = @StrategyID,      
      [Dateupdated] = Getdate()      
    Where  [Id] = @ID      
      And [Subsuserid] = @SubsUserID         
   End   
  --Process Record  

  SET @K = @K+1  
 END  
 --LOOP THROUGH RECORDS
```

Value of **@PnL** becomes wrong.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: *"but calculation goes bad"* What does that mean?  Explain the problem. Are you getting an error? Getting unexpected results? Your calculation turns to the dark side? It goes rotten? "goes bad" doesn't mean anything to us.

Comment: Every row calculates profit based on previous rows. Now one row is missing from the calculation and profit goes wrong. But putting Thread.Sleep before opening connection resolves the issue. I don't know how!

Comment: added stored procedure too

Comment: That procedure could do some major work, if I am honest. You loop through a table, which is rarely the right solution in T-SQL, however, you treat the table like it contains a single row; that makes no sense.

Comment: Agreed, it looks like you need a `MERGE` or something like that, and possibly a dash of window functions. You have *two* loops and you are creating, filling and dropping a temp table within the outer one

Comment: Also you're creating the table data to insert in c# code inside a For. why don't do calcs there?

Comment: Agreed l, but how it works fine when i put thread.sleep before connection?